# Possible Glitch When Trying to Edit Deck in Hearthstone

Tags: hearthstone

I lost all of my cards whilst playing Warlock in a ranked game (started drawing dead - only just lost / more suicide than anything)... well when I went to edit my warlock cards, I couldn't anymore. Is this part of the gameplay or a glitch?

Comment: We'll need more details than this. What exactly happens if you go to your collections, click on your deck and try to replace cards?

Comment: The pack that ran out whilst I was playing the game is no longer available to edit from within collections. I am still able to create a new pack. This is why I wasn't sure if this was written into the game. If I click on the deck that I was using in that game (from collections), it makes the noise that it makes when selecting any other deck, but it does not go through to that screen. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: - furthermore, I can still play with my previous pack but cannot make edits to it. I can make changes to all other decks.

Comment: Sounds like a simple bug to me.

Answer (score 3):

There are no restrictions on creating, editing or deleting decks. You can never lose cards through game play, only through disenchanting in "My Collections".

If you experience an interface bug, and restarting the client doesn't resolve the issue - use the [bug report forum](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/10591462/).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply... this does mean that this is a bug as once logged out, restarted, cache cleared and back in, the same problem persists. I attempted to report this as a bug yet was told on the website "You need a BattleTag and a trial game license or a full license to post on the official Hearthstone forums." which I can only assume I do not have. I am logged into the forum under my username and still am unable to post hence I reported here.

Answer (score -1):

seems your account was logged somewhere else exactly when you started playing and someone disenchanted your cards or due to a server bug you got your account reset. account resets are possible but only doable by blizzard employees

Comment: i actually reset my account using blizzard customer support, so whoever voted this down could at least come up with an explanation :)